# Async usage for Loading/Saving a list of objects to files

Tags: multithreading, asynchronous, io, parallel-processing

Let's say I have a list of same-class objects packed into a single file which I save to/load from at application startup.

What I'd like to do is use the power of async processing to speed up load-all time & save-all time - let's also assume that the files themselves are efficiently packed (using Protocol Buffers or the like).

**What would be the best way to go about this? Would async processing actually help in this scenario?**

One method I thought of is to "pre-determine" the amount of chunking by picking a number greater than 1, dividing the list up by that number, then saving/loading using that number as the number of tasks. However, this seems somewhat arbitrary, & I was curious if there are some libraries out there that might just make the decision for me based on some conditions.

I.e. I might call my "chunkable list" something like:

```
Chunkable<List<SomeObject>>
```

.. and then the program would just divide up the list correctly to read/save in an efficient way - e.g. save 10 files like "List_01", "List_XX" - then read from the chunks when performing  a load-all.

The final ordering of the list, when saving or loading, is not important - just having the objects available as a single list.

Comment: Is the bottleneck actually CPU, or IO? Because spreading the IO across multiple files isn't likely to speed it up...

Comment: A helpful comment, & in the example I'm thinking of I'm not sure - but for argument's sake, let's say it's CPU - i.e. there's some reasonable amount of processing to translate the serialization format back into a chunk of objects.

Comment: You might want to look at the Task Parallel Library (Parallel.ForEach etc) and also TPL Dataflow.

Comment: That's actually how I got here - take save-all as an example - let's say I do serialization with Task Parallel Lib (solves the CPU bit), but now I have to wait for everything to complete before writing the file - wouldn't it be better to just write things out to separate files as they complete? That's where it gets a bit confusing to me - should I predetermine the number of files - or perhaps I'm thinking about the IO wrong?

Comment: I would expect you to be able to do it all with TPL, but I don't have time to check exactly which call right now. It's very handy that the order doesn't matter... that may make it a better target for TPL Dataflow... basically one block for each file...

Comment: OK thanks - I'll take a closer look at TPL & TPL Dataflow - likely I'll understand the answer to my question better with more usage

Answer (score 0):

For posterity, one conceptual answer here is to use a Partitioner in the Task Parallel Library.

**For saving**, I can have the Partitioner serialize pieces of the list & write out files as tasks complete in a given non-repeating format.

**For loading**, I can get a count/list of the existing chunks in a given location on disk, then have the TPL load up & deserialize all the chunks & recombine them in whatever order they complete (using some Interlocked var to make sure each file is only read once).

I will paste code in here once I have tested some.